# Unable to get Store inside Sencha Controller

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm using Sencha Touch 2.3. I'm trying to get a Store instance inside a controller in a similar way thats defined in this article http://www.sencha.com/learn/architecting-your-app-in-ext-js-4-part-3/.

I've defined the 'Location' store in the Controller config. I then try to get the store using 2 methods that both fail. First through Ext.getStore and the second through getLocationStore which should be an autogenerated function. Both fail. The first call returns undefined and the second call throws an exception because the function is not available.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Location', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    refs: {
        locationSearchField: '#locationSearchField'
    },

    control: {
        locationSearchField: {
            action: 'onSearchAction'
        }
    },

    stores: [ 'Location' ]

},

onSearchAction: function() {
    var locationSearchStore = Ext.getStore('Location');
    if (locationSearchStore == undefined) {
        Ext.Logger.warn('Could not locate locationSearchStore');
        locationSearchStore = this.getLocationStore();
        if (locationSearchStore == undefined)
            Ext.Logger.warn('Could not location locationSearchStore again!');
        else
            Ext.Logger.info('Success!');
    }   
    else
        Ext.Logger.info('Success!');

}
```

});

Comment: Try this.getStore('Location')

Comment: Where is your store definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your store by: `Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('Location'`) (if it's called `MyApp.store.Location`).

To be sure, that you are in the right context in the `onSearchAction`, try to call `console.dir(this);` and check that `this` is the controller object itself

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want to access store in sencha touch but you have given link of extjs. Second, you need to define your store first and then add it in app.js file. And then you can access your store by `Ext.getStore('Location')` method. For reference you shold learn this http://miamicoder.com/2012/sencha-touch-2-stores-adding-removing-and-finding-records/